# Query from one table base on query from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have 2 tables `logins` and `tickets`. Table `logins` has columns `userName` (ex: jbrown) and `StaffName` (ex: John Brown), table `tickets` has a column `SMEName` that relates to `StaffName`.

What I want to do is based on the `userName` entered, find the `StaffName` in `logins` and then based on that `StaffName/SMEName`, find all the records for that person in my `tickets` table.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bcasp_GetTicketByOwnership] 
    @login NVARCHAR(255),
    @staff NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT StaffName
    FROM logins
    WHERE username = @login    
    @staff = StaffName

    SELECT 
        ID, TicketNumber, SMEName, 
        DateRequestCreated, 
        Complexity
    FROM 
        T_Ticket
    WHERE 
        SMEName = @staff
END
```

This throws an incorrect syntax error at

```
@staff = StaffName
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously this is the wrong syntax `WHERE username = @login @staff = StaffName`.  You're missing `AND` between the two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the AND clause, 
this is the correct code :

```
SELECT
StaffName
FROM logins
WHERE username = @login 
AND @staff = StaffName
```

Comment: Argh! That did it. The `AND` looked grey-out in y SQL window and I thought that meant there was something wrong, but it worked.

Comment: Glad i helped you, you can put this as answered